# Determining expectation value two interacting spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics

My problem is this:
Consider two interacting spins-$1/2, \mathcal{H}_1 = \mathcal{H}_2 = span(|\downarrow\rangle|, |\uparrow\rangle)$, with $\langle m | m' \rangle = \delta_{mm'}$, $\langle m |\hat{S}^a| m'\rangle = 1/2[\sigma^{a}]_{mm'}$, for Pauli matrices $\sigma^{a}, (a = x, y, z), m = \downarrow, \uparrow$ and $\hat{S}_{tot}^a := \hat{S}^a \otimes \mathbb{1} + \mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{S}^a$. Determine $\langle \psi |\hat{S}_{tot}^a| \psi \rangle$ with $a = z, x$ for $\psi = |\downarrow\rangle \otimes  |\downarrow\rangle$.

I don't have a physics background and I think what's messing with me the most is the notation as well as the fact I'm not sure how to find $\langle \psi |\hat{S}_{tot}^a| \psi \rangle$ for $a = z, x$. Is $\hat{S}_{tot}^{z, x} = \hat{S}^z \otimes \mathbb{1} + \mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{S}^x$? But from what I know about rotations should I be taking the tensor product of $\hat{S}_{tot}^z$ and $\hat{S}_{tot}^x$-but then again, I know it's different for quantum systems. Also, what does $[\sigma^{a}]_{mm'}$  mean? I understand $\sigma^a$ is the Pauli matrix but what do the brackets represent (a commutator of the matrix with itself?) as well as the subscripts-something about the $\delta$ function, but I'm not sure what. And finally, does $\delta_{mm'}$ refer to the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$ or the Dirac delta $\delta(x - x_0)$ as a distribution? I couldn't find answers anywhere (or I'm looking in the wrong places) so I'm sorry if this has all been on here before.

Comment: $a=z,x$ means $a \in \{z,x\}$ (so e.g. $S^{x}_{tot} = S^x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes S^x$). $[\sigma^a]_{mm'}$ means the matrix element of $\sigma^a$ for the $m$-th row and $m'$-th column. Brackets are just for clarity, nothing more. $\delta_{mm'}$ is the Kronecker delta of course, you are dealing with indices, not coordinates.

Comment: The space you need to consider is a direct product of two Hilbert spaces. So the Stot operator is acting in the two spaces independently which is why it’s given in that form.

Comment: You are considering two separable Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ over the complex field $\mathbb{C}$. So $S_{tot}^a$ is nothing but $S_{tot}^a = S^a_1 \otimes \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{H}_2} + \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{H}_1} \otimes S^a_2$ where $a \in \{x,y,z\}$. $S_{tot}$ works on elements in $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$. So in the usual way: $(f \otimes g)(x,y) = f(x) \cdot g(y)$ for $f: V \rightarrow V$, $g: W \rightarrow W$, $(x,y) \in V \times W$ where $W,V$ are (in this case) finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Here they are even Hilbert spaces

Comment: One often writes $(f \otimes g)(x \otimes y) = f(x)\cdot g(y)$ instead of my previous comment